# The task of proving the identity of expectation

Tags: probability, problem-solving

The random variable X only accepts
non-negative integer values. Prove that for
any whole $2 \leq r $

$EX(X-1)...(X-r+1)=r\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{r-1}P\{{X > n \}}$

I tried to use this identity for a solution, but nothing worked

$EX=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}P\{{X\geq r\}}$

Also,i tried using genereting function $\phi(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}s^nP\{{X=n\}}$,then $\phi^{(r)}(1)=EX(X-1)...(X-r+1)$, but that didn’t help either

Comment: So if X is 0.9 with 100 percent probability then EX(X-1)=0?

Comment: X only accepts non-negative integer values

Comment: The identity is completely false. Take $X\equiv 2$

Comment: On the other hand, $$E X^r = \int_0^\infty P(X\geq t)rt^{r-1}\,dt$$ Now specialize to the case where $X$ is supported on $\mathbb Z_+$

Comment: This is a genrealisation of what's known as the "Darth Vader" rule for computing expectation using survivor function.